# How are wctype.h functions supposed to be used correctly?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, ctype

The various `is...` functions (e.g. `isalpha`, `isdigit`) in `ctype.h` aren't entirely predictable.  They take `int` arguments but expect character values in the `unsigned char` range, so on a platform where `char` is signed, passing a `char` value directly could lead to undesirable sign extension.  I believe that the typical approach to handling this is to explicitly cast to an `unsigned char` first.

Okay, but what is the proper, portable way to deal with the various `isw...` functions in `wctype.h`?  `wchar_t`, like `char`, also may be signed or unsigned, but because `wchar_t` is itself a `typedef`, a typename of `unsigned wchar_t` is illegal.

Comment: Why is sign extension a problem?

Comment: @Mat: The `is...` functions expect values in the `unsigned char` range.  If you give them a different value, you'll get undefined behavior.  A specific example is that if your character value happens to be `-1`, it'll likely be treated as `EOF`.

Comment: Good point, I never realized they were specified that way.

Comment: you don't need to cast to unsigned char. Since int is 16 or more there won't be sign extension. In case the character is 0xFF it will be converted to 0x00FF or 0x000000FF when passed to isalpha, etc.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: Huh?  If you're storing `0xFF` in a signed `char`, then when it is promoted to, say, a 32-bit `int`, it will become `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: did I mention signed char somewhere? If you are dealing with real characters, then you should be working with unsigned chars. isalpha() and others are expecting an unsigned char in 99.99% of cases, unless you are compiling for unicode, of couse.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: No. `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon re-reading the ISO C99 specification regarding `wctype.h`, it states:

> For all functions described in this subclause that accept an argument of type `wint_t`, the value shall be representable as a `wchar_t` or shall equal the value of the macro `WEOF`. If this argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined. (§7.25.1/5)

Contrast this with the corresponding note for `ctype.h`:

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
> representable as an **`unsigned char`** or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined. (§7.4/1)

(emphasis mine)

I think that it's also worth understanding the motivation for why the `ctype.h` functions require `unsigned char` representations.  The standard *requires* that `EOF` be a negative `int` (§7.19.1/3), so the `ctype.h` functions use `unsigned char` representations to (try to) avoid potential ambiguity.

In contrast, that motivation doesn't exist for `wctype.h` functions.  The standard makes no such requirement of `WEOF`, elaborated by footnote 270:

> The value of the macro `WEOF` may differ from that of `EOF` and need not be negative.

because `WEOF` is already guaranteed to not conflict with any character represented by `wchar_t` (§7.24.1/3).

Therefore the `wctype.h` functions don't have or need any of the unsigned nonsense, and `wchar_t` values can be passed to them directly.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that what `wint_t` is for?  The `iswXxxxx()` functions take a `wint_t` type:

ISO 9899:1999 covers this in various sections, working backwards:

> ### §7.25 Wide character classification and mapping utilities `<wctype.h>`
>
> #### §7.25.2.1.1 The iswalnum function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <wctype.h>
> int iswalnum(wint_t wc);
> ```
>
> Description
>
> The iswalnum function tests for any wide character for which iswalpha or iswdigit is true.
>
> ### §7.24 Extended multibyte and wide character utilities `<wchar.h>`
>
> #### §7.24.1 Introduction:
>
> ```
> wint_t
> ```
>
> which is an integer type unchanged by default argument promotions that can hold any
>   value corresponding to members of the extended character set, as well as at least one
>   value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set (see WEOF
>   below);<sup>269)</sup>
>
> <sup>269)</sup> `wchar_t` and `wint_t` can be the same integer type.

The 'unchanged by default argument promotions' should mean that it has to be as big as an `int`, though it could be a `short` or `unsigned short` if `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` (which is seldom the case these days, though it was true for some 16-bit systems).

> ### §7.17 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`
>
> ```
> wchar_t
> ```
>
> which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all
>   members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales; the
>   null character shall have the code value zero and each member of the basic character set
>   shall have a code value equal to its value when used as the lone character in an integer
>   character constant.

As long as the value passed to `iswalnum()` or its kin is a valid `wchar_t` or WEOF, the function will work correctly.  If you manufactured the value out of thin air and manage to get the value wrong, you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm not entirely following.  That `wint_t` is unchanged by promotion doesn't mean that `wchar_t` is unchanged when promoting to `wint_t`. The normal `is...` functions take `int` instead of `char`; the `isw...` functions analogously take `wint_t` instead of `wchar_t`.  What makes the second case different?

Comment: Ok, pondering your references got me pointed in the right direction, and I think I now know why the two cases are not completely analogous. (See my answer to my own question.)